# About the congruence.

Tags: number-theory

I dont know how to prove this question. I can only get $a^{m^s} ≡ b^{m^s}$ ( mod $m^r$).

Suppose $m$ and $r$ are  positive  integers.   If $a ≡ b$ (mod $m^r$ ),  then  for  each
$s \geq 0$, $a^{m^s}
≡ b^{m^s}$ (mod $m^{r + s}$ )

Comment: Hint: Prove it by induction on $s$.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show it for $s=1$, since this implies inductively that it is true for greater valueas of $s$.

And $a^m-b^m=(a-b)\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a^jb^{m-j-1}$. Since the factor $a-b$ is multiple of $m^r$, it suffices to show that $m$ divides $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a^jb^{m-j-1}$, but

$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a^jb^{m-j-1}\equiv \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a^ja^{m-j-1}\equiv ma^{m-1}\equiv0\pmod m$$